Problem integrating 3D Swiss tiles from the API to A-Frame for virtual reality
Good morning,
I am a Swiss student who would like to integrate Swiss data into A-Frame via an API.
Here is the API link: API geo.admin
and here is an example of a request which returns us a json: example json
If my savior comes through that would be incredible...
Thank you in advance for your help.
I tried several ways and components, so this one works with Google tiles but not with Swiss tiles.
components
I don't know how to solve my problem?
Do you have an idea for a solution? or is it impossible?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
